# How to create colours combination like attached image?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode7

I want to create background like the attached image in Xcode. Any suggestions?

[image]

Comment: can't see an attachment.

Comment: edited with the image

Comment: use this image as UINavigationBar's background image

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Best way is always use Image as background

[image]

```
let navBackgroundImage:UIImage! = UIImage(named: "your_background_image_name_here")
```

**If you want to set for only view controller**

```
self.navigationController.navigationBar.setBackgroundImage(navBackgroundImage, 
                                                   forBarMetrics: .Default)
```

**If you want to set for all screens**, add below line in AppDelegate's `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions` method

```
[UINavigationBar .appearance().setBackgroundImage(navBackgroundImage, forBarMetrics:.Default)]
```

Answer (score 1):

If you're in a View Controller, write the following code in viewDidLoad() or wherever appropriate.

```
let gradientLayer = CAGradientLayer()
gradientLayer.frame = self.view.bounds
let color1 = UIColor(red: 238.0/255.0, green: 54.0/255.0, blue: 97.0/255.0, alpha: 1.0).CGColor as CGColorRef
let color2 = UIColor(red: 238.0/255.0, green: 89.0/255.0, blue: 59.0/255.0, alpha: 1.0).CGColor as CGColorRef
gradientLayer.colors = [color1, color2]
gradientLayer.locations = [0.0, 0.5]
self.view.layer.addSublayer(gradientLayer)
```

The color1 and color2 were picked by a color picker from your image. Please use accurate RGB values for the top-most and bottom-most colors.

Comment: Thanks Vishal for the quick response. As I see that it added a sublayer in front of the view i have two buttons on that view now they are hidden. Any Suggestions ?

Comment: My bad, I was only thought of the code for the gradient.

Comment: self.view.layer.insertSublayer(gradientLayer, atIndex: 0) This will work.

Comment: I'm sorry, the code I shared would add the layer to the entire view of the VC. First tell me if you're using a custom Navigation bar or the system one?

Comment: @niks290192: That's awesome. Kudos.

Answer (score 0):

```
CAGradientLayer *gradient = [CAGradientLayer layer];
gradient.frame = self.view.bounds;
gradient.colors = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:(id)[[UIColor colorWithRed:152.0/255.0 green:185.0/255.0 blue:252.0/255.0 alpha:1.0] CGColor], (id)[[UIColor colorWithRed:38.0/255.0 green:63.0/255.0 blue:123.0/255.0 alpha:1.0] CGColor], nil];
[self.view.layer insertSublayer:gradient atIndex:0];
```

By adding sublayer at zero (0) index worked for me.

Comment: Thanks For the Reply my initial question was in Swift. Anyways I figured the way as you said sublayer to index 0 (y).